# WPF - access to resources in design time when App.xaml's Build Action = Page

Tags: wpf, resources

I changed the build action of my App.xaml to "Page" so I could handle a splash screen and make sure my application run as a single instance only (having my own entry point).
It works fine in run-time but in design-time the application cannot see the my resources anymore. Resources are in separate xaml files located in the same project.
How can I make my app see the resources in design-time again?

Thanks

Comment: I can switch back and forth - change App.xaml's build action to Page when I am ready to publish and switch it back when in development. But is this what I am supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you're loading Application-wide resources in the app.xaml? In this case you can do like this:

```
App app = new App();
//Get assembly name is your own method
string assemblyName = GetAssemblyName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

Uri resourceLocater = new Uri("/" + assemblyName + ";component/app.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(app, resourceLocater);
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
app.Run(mainWindow);
```

Then your resources will be loaded

/Daniel

Comment: The original question says that the problem only occurs at design-time. It appears to me that the above code will have no effect at design-time. What am I missing? (I have the same problem: it works fine at runtime, but I get 'StaticResource reference ... not found error' at design-time)

Comment: It won't help. See the answer I just added. Gustavo, why did you mark this as correct?

Answer (score 6):

Factor your resources out into a separate resource dictionary and then pull them into App.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MasterResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

You can add multiple resource dictionaries this way as needed.

You also need to do the same thing in UserControls (and Windows that reference UserControls using the resources):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MasterResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

See http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/Merging-Resource-Dictionaries-for-fun-and-profit.aspx for more on this topic.

Comment: When I've used this approach, I've ended up with separate copies of the resources defined in MasterResources.xaml for each UserControl that merges them in, which leads to memory horribleness.

Comment: Exactly. The sharing or graphics resources and styles between UI components is a key aspect of coding a WPF UI, yet there doesn't seem to be any support for it in design mode at all, and the MS recommendation to just copy the resources everywhere you use them is plain nonsense.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The link in particular describes exactly the same scenario that was raised in the question.  I've also came across the same problem, and found that sadly merging dictionaries into every single window and usercontrol seems to be the only solution to designer failing to resolve resources.  WPF is supposed to be this great technology, but lately I feel like I'm forced to use one hack after another to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are calling `InitializeComponent()` as the first line of your application's constructor:

```
public App()
{
    // This is the method generated by VisualStudio that initializes
    // the application from associated XAML file
    InitializeComponent();

    // Do everything else
}
```

Comment: OMG, I mean OMFG.  I have been struggling with the designer not finding my static resources in a separate control's project, where the main project has the app.xaml which loads and merges the dictionaries.  Creating an App.xaml in the controls project and then stripping it down to just have the resource dictionaries and that InitializeComponent() call did something totally unexpected - it worked! the controls within controls are now rendering instead of complaining about the missing resources, the intellisense errors in the xaml view are gone too - oh happy day!!!!