# WPF Design Time Loading of Global Resources When Build Action is Page

Tags: wpf, app.xaml

I have a WPF application that I added my own Sub Main() to do some processing and display an animated splash screen before the main window loads.  Part of the process to make this work involved changing the Build Action on the Application.xaml to 'Page' rather than 'ApplicationDefinition'.

Everything is working well at runtime, but in the VS designer my main window has problems loading user controls on its surface.  Looking deeper it appears that the user control cannot find a style resource located in the Application.xaml resources - at least at design time.  At run time there is no problem.

I assume that somehow switching from 'AppicationDefinition' to 'Page' for the build action of the Application.xaml has somehow disconnected the application's ability to load resources at design time.

There is an article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855497/wpf-access-to-resources-in-design-time-when-app-xamls-build-action-page) that describes the same issue I am having, but the solution was incorrectly marked as an answer because it clearly doesn't address the design time issue.  Another person answered, but that solution was to simply instantiate resources all over the place, rather than in a single location - not what I want.

I found an article by Josh Smith [here](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/assembly-level-initialization-at-design-time/) which seems very promising about executing your own code when the application loads at design time, but I don't know what to put in after the 'TODO' section code.  I'm thinking somehow call Initialize component on my Application class, but that isn't instantiated at design time...right?

```
    'In AssemblyInfo.vb
    <AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)> _
    Class DesignTimeBootstrapperAttribute
        Inherits Attribute
        Public Sub New()
            Dim dep = New DependencyObject()
            If DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(dep) Then
                ' TODO: Design-time initialization…
                'Not sure how to get application level resources to load at design time?
            End If
        End Sub
```

So my question is:
How do I  get the application to initialize and load the resources in the application.xaml at design time so my designer correctly displays the styled user controls?  Or alternatively, how can I declare these global resources so they will work at both design and run times?